# to get this client server android app working. what IP address do I type in the edittext window?

Tags: android, sockets, client-server

I have two android tablets that I want to send messages from the client to the server with socket programming.  I pasted the sample code to make the server and client apps and installed them on two android tablets.  both connected to wifi

on the client app there is an edit text that i am supposed to type in an IP address in it then the button below that is called "connect phones".

what IP address am i supposed to type in the edittext before clicking the "connect phones button"

here is the onclick listener for the "connect phones" button

```
    private OnClickListener connectListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!connected) {
            serverIpAddress = serverIp.getText().toString();
            if (!serverIpAddress.equals("")) {
                Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                cThread.start();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

full code for both client and server apps shown below;

client code:

```
 package com.example.client;

 // import statements

 public class ClientActivity extends Activity {

private EditText serverIp;

private Button connectPhones;

private String serverIpAddress = "";

private boolean connected = false;

private Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.client);

    serverIp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.server_ip);
    connectPhones = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect_phones);
    connectPhones.setOnClickListener(connectListener);
}

private OnClickListener connectListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!connected) {
            serverIpAddress = serverIp.getText().toString();
            if (!serverIpAddress.equals("")) {
                Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                cThread.start();
            }
        }
    }
};

public class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Connecting...");
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 8080);
            connected = true;
            while (connected) {
                try {
                    Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sending command.");
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket
                                .getOutputStream())), true);
                        // where you issue the commands
                        out.println("Hey Server!");
                        Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sent.");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error", e);
                }
            }
            socket.close();
            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Closed.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Error", e);
            connected = false;
        }
    }
 }
 }
```

server code;

```
       package com.example.server;

  // import statements

  public class ServerActivity extends Activity {

private TextView serverStatus;

// default ip
// public static String SERVERIP ="10.0.2.15";

// designate a port
public static final int SERVERPORT = 8080;

private Handler handler = new Handler();

private ServerSocket serverSocket;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.server);
    serverStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.server_status);

    SERVERIP = getLocalIpAddress();

    Thread fst = new Thread(new ServerThread());
    fst.start();
}

    public class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        try {
            if (SERVERIP != null) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        serverStatus.setText("Listening on IP: " + SERVERIP);
                    }
                });
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
                while (true) {
                    // listen for incoming clients
                    Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            serverStatus.setText("Connected.");
                        }
                    });

                    try {
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                            Log.d("ServerActivity", line);
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // do whatever you want to the front end
                                    // this is where you can be creative
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        break;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                serverStatus.setText("Oops. Connection interrupted. Please reconnect your phones.");
                            }
                        });
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        serverStatus.setText("Couldn't detect internet connection.");
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    serverStatus.setText("Error");
                }
            });
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

// gets the ip address of your phone's network
private String getLocalIpAddress() {
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) { return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString(); }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Log.e("ServerActivity", ex.toString());
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    try {
         // make sure you close the socket upon exiting
         serverSocket.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}

 }
```

logcat errors;

```
01-22 18:37:40.100: E/ClientActivity(19568): C: Error
01-22 18:37:40.100: E/ClientActivity(19568): java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.15 (port 8080): connect failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
01-22 18:37:40.100: E/ClientActivity(19568):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
01-22 18:37:40.100: E/ClientActivity(19568):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
01-22 18:37:40.100: E/ClientActivity(19568):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
01-22 18:37:40.100: E/ClientActivity(19568):    at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:566)
01-22 18:37:40.100: E/ClientActivity(19568):    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:225)
01-22 18:37:40.100: E/ClientActivity(19568):    at com.example.client.ClientActivity$ClientThread.run(ClientActivity.java:60)
01-22 18:37:40.100: E/ClientActivity(19568):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-22 18:37:40.100: E/ClientActivity(19568): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
01-22 18:37:40.100: E/ClientActivity(19568):    at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
01-22 18:37:40.100: E/ClientActivity(19568):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
01-22 18:37:40.100: E/ClientActivity(19568):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
01-22 18:37:40.100: E/ClientActivity(19568):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
```

Comment: put proper permissions before you connect it: internet permission

Comment: already got the permissions set in my manifest file

Comment: i just put the logcat error messages at the bottom of my question

Comment: i used at java method to get the local IP address as you told me to do and made it display it to a textview.  it is a strange looking IP address not all numbers.  this is it; fe80::96db:c9ff:fe08:6f39%wlan0   does that look like an IP address to you?

Comment: i wonder if this will work with IP version 6 addresses. these are hexidecimal numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.connect two device with a network (WIFI)
2.you can get ip address of each device via programmatically in android
3.and make a textview which shows the two ip address
4.type it in both connect it

Comment: you said "type in both"   i thought that i only type in one IP address either the client or server there is only one place to type in an IP address

Comment: oh sorry.just type in one ..it will connected

Answer (score 1):

When you connect your android device to a WiFi network, it is assigned an IP address. This IP address is visible under the "Settings > About Phone > Status > IP Address" . Now, in your case, the server app runs on one tablet, and client on the other. We need the IP address of the Server only, which you can find out using this method. Enter this IP in the client applications corresponding area, and you're set
.

Answer (score 0):

You should enter server IP at client side to request connection. Server listens to a specific port. If your server side app is displaying an IP address, put it in the client app to make connection. If your server app is not displaying anything, just go to settings> about> status and find the IP address. From your server side code, it is clearly given:

```
serverStatus.setText("Listening on IP: " + SERVERIP);
```

Put this in your client.